# Protected Pages configuration not showing in admin/config/system

Tags: 7

I am trying to use the [Protected Pages](https://drupal.org/project/protected_pages) module, using drupal version 7.24

I have installed and enable the module, applied the module's permissions (which are visible under /admin/people/permissions#module-protected_pages) but the configuration menu is not visible in admin/config/system as documented. In the permissions menu, I have allowed anyone to access to the configuration page, but to no avail.

Manually navigating to admin/config/system/protected_pages does not work (just defaults to admin/config/system/)

Is there thing that I can do to either get it to show up or manually edit the settings?